# LIRC error while trying to read file for AC controlling

Tags: pi-4, lirc

After going through the steps mentioned in [this](https://devkimchi.com/2020/08/12/turning-raspberry-pi-into-remote-controller/) tutorial, it all worked fine until the IR receiver(where I had a small issue of false input detection). When I tried to run `sudo /etc/init.d/lircd status` after recording the inputs and restarting, I received the following error.

```
Dec 07 06:07:40 raspberrypi lircd-0.10.1[543]: Notice: Using systemd fd
Dec 07 06:07:40 raspberrypi lircd-0.10.1[543]: Warning: Running as root
Dec 07 06:07:40 raspberrypi lircd-0.10.1[543]: Info: Using remote: ACT.
Dec 07 06:07:40 raspberrypi lircd-0.10.1[543]: Info: Using remote: RemTi.
Dec 07 06:07:40 raspberrypi lircd-0.10.1[543]: Error: error in configfile line 118:
Dec 07 06:07:40 raspberrypi lircd-0.10.1[543]: Error: bad signal length
Dec 07 06:07:40 raspberrypi lircd-0.10.1[543]: Error: reading of file '/etc/lirc/lircd.conf.d/RCTx.lircd.conf' failed
Dec 07 06:07:40 raspberrypi lircd-0.10.1[543]: Warning: config file /etc/lirc/lircd.conf contains no valid remot…inition
Dec 07 06:07:40 raspberrypi lircd-0.10.1[543]: Notice: lircd(default) ready, using /var/run/lirc/lircd
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

This is how my input file somewhat looks like(I was unable to copy my exact input file):

```
begin remote

  name   tv
  flags RAW_CODES
  eps            25
  aeps          100

  ptrail          0
  repeat     0     0
  gap    20921


  begin raw_codes

    name SWITCH_ON
     8996     4451      552      574      551      576
      552      576      551      579      550      575
      553     1683      577      550      551     1683
      ...
      564

     9000     4453      578      548      580      548
      578      549      556      572      552      576
      552     1683      577      551      550     1683
      ...
      573
     

  end raw_codes
end remote
```

In the same tutorial link, the editor too faced a problem with controlling his AC.
I believe it is because of 2 parts of decoding over here.
What I mean is, that one button forms 2 blocks and I think that might be conflicting with it.

Is there any solution?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: some ACs use a type of rolling code that changes with every button press

Comment: What do I do now?

Comment: Is it that I cannot control my AC with this at all now?